# Deploy from maven released repository to application

Tags: cloudbees

I just figured out, how to release to CB hosted maven "release" repository. I am trying to figure out, how to deploy tagged version to CB application. 
I understand, I can manually upload WAR file but is there any script. As far as I know maven plugin for CB doesn't support it.

I have one appserver is running snapshot builds from jenkins. 
I have other appserver, which I want to deploy only tagged/released artifact.

Comment: Sorry for the question, but... what does "CB" mean?

Answer (score 1):

There are four ways to deploy applications to the CloudBees RUN@cloud service:

1. Using the `bees` command provided by the SDK
2. Using the `bees-maven-plugin`
3. Using the manual upload via the web GUI
4. Using the CloudBees Deployer plugin for Jenkins

Which option you choose depends on where the deployment will take place from... And the from I am talking about is which *machine* is doing the deployment not where the file is sourced.

If running from a Jenkins job, the best bet is the Jenkins plugin.

If running from your own laptop, the web ui or the `bees` command is simplest.

If running as part of a maven build, the maven plugin is simplest... (Though I should warn that the maven plugin (temporarily removing my cloudbees hat and putting on my maven PMC hat) is shite and does it all arsewise ;-) )

Your best bet is to set up a Jenkins job that uses dependency:get to pull the artifact from the repo and then add a cloudbees deployer build step to push to RUN@cloud

The good news is that bashing the maven plugin into something more maven like is on our roadmap... Hopefully that will enable actions like you can achieve with the ship-maven-plugin@mojo where you can specify a specific released version for "shipping" to production.

Comment: Thanks, from your reply above -> "our best bet is to set up a Jenkins job that uses dependency:get to pull the artifact from the repo "  Can you be more specific? In my case I want to deploy [https://repository-ajainy.forge.cloudbees.com/release/jframeworks/demandship-api/1.0.2/demandship-api-1.0.2.war].  <br/> Q1: What kind of new job, i should do setup? Build Maven project? if yes, I need to put something on "Goals and options? <br/>

Comment: Oh I never use the maven project type... That is a long running disagreement between myself and Kohsuke. But in any case either should work, but you will be using a separate `pom.xml` to do the file grabbing, or else playing magic with system properties and a parameterized build. I will see if I can put an example together when my wide lets me back near my computer and I am no longer limited to a fruity phone

Comment: I am playing with jenkins new job. Keep you updated. I am getting error: <code>ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:get (default-cli) on project demandship-api: The parameters 'repositoryUrl' or goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:get are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]</code>

Comment: See [remoteRepositories](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html#remoteRepositories) also if not using a `pom.xml` you will need to fully specify, eg `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.6:get -DremoteRepositories=...` you'll need to stack up all the properties. You should be able to test this on the CLI locally, remember that the repo URL format starts with the id from `settings.xml` followed by `::default::` and then the traditional URL.

Comment: I was able to use default plugin version. My maven command looked like --> Executing Maven: "  -B -f /scratch/jenkins/workspace/Tag Deployer/pom.xml dependency:get -DrepoId=cloudbees-private-release-repository -DrepoUrl=https://repository-ajainy.forge.cloudbees.com/release -Dversion=1.0.2 -Dpackaging=war -DgroupId=jframeworks -DartifactId=demandship-api ".  Now deploying downloaded war file to appserver. It failed. I am using "**/*.war" war file format.

Comment: Try `**/*.war` as `**/.war` won't match anything

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, that what you want to do is to deploy a release artifact to your repository.

have a look at [maven-release-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/).

Briefly, what you need to do is:

```
$ mvn release:prepare
$ mvn release:perform
```

it's not so trivial, since you need to configure appropriately your pom.xml to get it working. Have a look at the [maven-release-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/) examples and usage pages.

Comment: Thanks Luigi. Infact, I already released my artifact. Now I want to know, how to deploy "released" artifact to CB hosted application server. (other than manual upload WAR file)

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating the tag/release from a Jenkins build? If so you could probably use the Deploy to CloudBees post-build step with `target/checkout/something.war`.

More generally I guess you would want to write a script to use `mvn dependency:get` followed by the Bees SDK to obtain the latest released artifact and deploy it.

Comment: I created tag/release using maven release plugin. Not sure, if it's good idea to cut a tag without testing & deploying on some test app server. I am open to suggestions for lifecycle of code releases.